# How to USE GET method with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I cannot get a value of `$id_pinjam = @$_GET['id_pinjam'];` here's PHP code

```
<?php

include '../../inc/koneksi.php';

$id_pinjam = @$_GET['id_pinjam'];       
$tgl_kembali = date("Y-m-d");   

$queryResult = $db->query("SELECT * FROM detail_pinjam WHERE id_pinjam = '$id_pinjam'") or die($db->error); 

echo $id_pinjam."<br>";

while($fetchData = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr>
            <td class='text-center'>".$fetchData['id_detail']."</td>
            <td class='text-center'>".$fetchData['id_pinjam']."</td>
            <td class='text-center'>".$fetchData['kode_pustaka']."</td>
            <td class='text-center'>".$fetchData['tgl_jatuh_tempo']."</td>
            <td class='text-center'></td><td class='text-center'></td></tr>";
}

?>
```

Here's jQuery code(to load data):

```
loadDataPinjam();
function loadDataPinjam(){

    var dataHandler = $("#load-data-pinjam-here");
    dataHandler.html("");

      $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      data : "",
      url : "proses/pinjam/getDataPinjam.php",
      success : function(result){
          var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);

          $.each(resultObj,function(key, val){
            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            newRow.html("<td class='text-center'>"+val.no_anggota+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+val.nama+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+val.alamat+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+val.id_pinjam+"<td class='text-center'>"+val.tgl_pinjam+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+val.jml_pinjam+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+val.status+"</td><td style='width: 20px;'><a href='?page=kembali&id_pinjam="+val.id_pinjam+"'><img src='img/return.png' class='icon'></a><input type='hidden' name='getIdPinjam' id='getIdPinjam' value='"+val.id_pinjam+"'></td>");
            dataHandler.append(newRow);

          });
        }
      });
}
```

and when i click link, GET parameter is not set, but when i set `$id_pinjam` manually than code is working. Help me to identify issue?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie in web programming, so i start from mysqli procedural style. and I'm not understand yet with OOP style,

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing `@` operator obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: The OOP style is a lot less verbose and a lot easier to understand since each function call has fewer parameters. If you're just getting started with MySQL and PHP it's probably not too late to switch over to PDO which is a lot more pleasant in practice.

Comment: @AgusPriyanto You have to pass variable that you want to use `url : "proses/pinjam/getDataPinjam.php?id_pinjam="+dataHandler`, only then you get that var in your PHP file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are sending nothing via Ajax.

Try:

```
url : "proses/pinjam/getDataPinjam.php?id_pinjam=YourValue",
```

Comment: I tried to declare a variable in my function like this var id = $("#getIdPinjam").val(); to add a value of <input type=hidden> and put that variable in url "proses/pinjam/getDataPinjam.php?id_pinjam="+id, and try to change <a href='?page=kembali&id_pinjam="+id+"'> but I didn't get any output

Comment: in newRow.html() <a href='?page=kembali&id_pinjam="+val.id_pinjam+"'> , and that link show query result of my PHP code, but I think my GET parameter is incorrect

Comment: Try to delete the +" in your a href?

Comment: That doesn't change anything, how about put my  var id = $("#getIdPinjam").val(); into id_pinjam parameter in <a href='?page=kembali&id_pinjam="myVar"'> ? how to put that variable ??

Comment: What exactly shall this program do? You want to click that link and then?

Comment: when i click the link, it shows records of table(pinjam) where id_pinjam = GET parameter of the link, but as you know, GET parameter didn't set to PHP

Answer (score 0):

**You can use below 2 methods for GET method in jQuery**

**1. Use $.get method**

Please check below link for reference:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

```
$.get("test.php", {number: numValue} , function(data){
  // Display the returned data in browser
});
```

**2. Standard $.ajax method**

```
$.ajax({  
   method: "GET",
   url: "some.php",
   data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.success(function( data ) {
   alert( "Data : " + data );
});
```

As per your above sample code you need to pass parameters while you call ajax method